# Magento Magmi: Attribute import for multiple stores/languages

Tags: magento, magmi

I have an attribute called "colour" in my shop and want to display the colour names in different languages. For product import I use MAGMI v0.7.18. The [MAGMI Wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Behaviour_-_select_&#x26_multiselect_attributes#New_.22Translation.22_syntax_.2C_from_0.7.15b) says:

Import admin values first:

```
"store","sku","myselect"
"admin","sku001","adminval1"
"admin","sku002","adminval2"
"admin","sku003","adminval3"
```

Once done, the following csv mockup will produce "translated" values:

```
"store","sku","myselect"
"store1","sku001","store1val1::[adminval1]"
"store2","sku001","store2val1::[adminval1]"
"store1","sku002","store1val2::[adminval2]"
"store2","sku002","store2val2::[adminval2]"
```

That´s exactly what I did!

My admin import:

```
"sku";"store";"color"
"1101401-401";"admin";"white"
```

My storeview import:

```
 "sku";"store";"color"
 "1101401-401";"deutsch";"weiß::[white]"
```

But after the import ist done, the attributes are muddled. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbrck.jpg).

Any idea about that problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you import the initial (English) values first, THEN try to do the translations on a second import?

Comment: Yes, I did. I have seperate files for each language and imported the "mater list" with admin values (German) and all other product information first (works fine, all attribute values are set to the admin column), after that I imported the German values for store view "deutsch", then the Italien values for store view "italiano" and at last the english values for stroe view "english".

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the cause was having the original and translated attribute titles in the wrong places.

I had

```
"white::[weiß]"
```

and it needs to be

```
"weiß::[white]"
```

where `white` was my original attribute value title